# Maze generation - Squared into circular

Tags: modeling, animation

Hi there i am having a problem with creating a squared maze that turns into a circular one as one goes to the middle of the maze.

I have tried several ways of doing it during the past few days and i just am not being able to do it.

I tried using the add-on "Maze mesh master" but im not able to generate circular mazes it keep giving error every time i try doing it on a circle instead of a square plane.
I also have tried creating the maze i want in illustrator and importing it as a SVG but for some reason the circular part of the maze looses its shape, i have done several tries of the illustrator - svg - blender method and the closes i got is this:

Maze made on illustrator with the help of some online generators
[image: square maze into circular - illustrator]

Maze inside blender
[image]

As you can see for the pathways are too narrow, and i kinda exhausted all methods i new on how i should create the maze.

The idea was creating a sort of garden maze, the maze being bushes but the pathways be wide enough for "people" to walk comfortably.

Hope i could more or less explain my conundrum :) i only started blender like this year so apologies for any butchering i might be doing.

Regards
ASilva

**EDIT:** The images are the best results i could accomplish with illustrator - SVG - Blender route

In doing this post i was hoping to find a way to create the same type of maze inside blender witch i have been trying to find and cant find witch was the main reason for going the illustrator route but i am not getting the result i want so i thought i would ask here if there was a different approach i could take.

Comment: I do not see where the circular part loses its shape...? Maybe the camera angle is too low to see it? And about the narrow pathways - well, they are a bit wider than the walls, just like in Illustrator. So if you had created them with wider pathways in Illustrator, they would be in Blender as well...

Comment: Can you mark the issue in the picture? I didnt get it what is the question here about ... sorry.

Comment: Of course you can build all this manually in Blender as well... for example by starting with a square face, extruding it out, building branches where you extrude in different directions etc. But if you are asking if there is some kind of automatic maze builder in Blender, then the answer is no. If this add-on you used does not help, then I can only wish you luck with finding another one. Or building it all manually.

Comment: well the add-on i found only lets me generate a squared maze, if it could generate a circular one it would be great but it doesn't.

i might try asking chat gpt to write me a python script and see if the script funtion in blender does something or if i cant find anything else manual labor it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As seen in my comment ... I don't know what is your issue with Illustrator's SVG, so it is hard for me to understand what do you need to solve on final mesh. Anyway here is some result from Blender with Geometry Nodes.*

---

I tried to recreate square to circle grid seen in your reference (the first GN modifier in my file)...

[image]
[image]

The second GN modifier is a maze generator ... **all credits go to [Hulifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304858/2214)** ... see his answer for more details and would be nice to upvote his answer if his answer works for you.

In my blend is *Maze 01* object with GN, just run animation (this GN is based on Simulation nodes).

[image]

Result with GN applied and with *Solidify* modifier (type Complex) is object *Maze_02*...

[image]

[image]

There is not probably a real path to reach a center, it is just an illusion of a maze :), but seems to me easy to adjust result to get one ... Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh (Ctr+A) and add/erase some walls.

[image]